# Decrypting/decompressing partial/incomplete PGP file

Tags: pgp

A client sends us text files via a third-party FTP service, which the client has encrypted and compressed with PGP.

Recently we have received incomplete or partial PGP files. Somehow, we can un-PGP these files and turn them back into TXT files, but they are incomplete; that is, they are cut off right in the middle of a row, somewhere in the file.

If a PGP file is somehow cut off in transmission, wouldn't it result in a bad file? How can a faulty or incomplete PGP file be un-PGP'ed? Wouldn't the PGP software (gpg.exe) error out and say the PGP file was invalid or something?